# Strange behive NSBitmapImageRep

Tags: macos, swift, cocoa

I try to build image. Pixel by pixel. So first I build some class which can draw by loops different color at each pixel. But it works nice only if alpha is set to 255. Changing alpha makes colors darker and changes picture. Size and place is OK.

```
 var rep:NSBitmapImageRep = NSBitmapImageRep(
                bitmapDataPlanes: nil,
                pixelsWide: width,
                pixelsHigh: height,
                bitsPerSample: 8,
                samplesPerPixel: 4,
                hasAlpha: true,
                isPlanar: false,
                colorSpaceName: NSDeviceRGBColorSpace,
                bytesPerRow: 0,
                bitsPerPixel: 0)!

 for posX in 0-offset...width+offset*2-1 {
      for  posY in  0-offset...height+offset*2-1 {

           var R = Int(Float(posX)/Float(width)*255)
           var G = Int(Float(posY)/Float(height)*255)
           var B = Int(rand() % 256)
           pixel = [R,G,B,alpha]
           rep.setPixel(&pixel, atX: posX, y: posY)
      }
 }

 rep.drawInRect(bounds)
```

[image: Alpha = 255]

alpha set to 255

[image: Alpha = 250]

alpha set to 196

[image: Alpha 127]

alpha equals 127 this time.

[image: alpha 63]

And 64.

Where i'm wrong?

Comment: It probably has something to do with the fact that you set `bitsPerRow` and `bytesPerPixel` to 0.

Comment: I changed to 
                bytesPerRow: 32*width,
                bitsPerPixel: 32)!
but nothing changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely problem is that you're not premultiplying the alpha with the color components.

From the [`NSBitmapImageRep` class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSBitmapImageRep_Class/):

> ### Alpha Premultiplication and Bitmap Formats
>
> When creating a bitmap using a premultiplied format, if a coverage
>   (alpha) plane exists, the bitmap’s color components are premultiplied
>   with it. In this case, if you modify the contents of the bitmap, you
>   are therefore responsible for premultiplying the data. Note that
>   premultiplying generally has negligible effect on output quality. For
>   floating-point image data, premultiplying color components is a
>   lossless operation, but for fixed-point image data, premultiplication
>   can introduce small rounding errors. In either case, more rounding
>   errors may appear when compositing many premultiplied images; however,
>   such errors are generally not readily visible.
>
> For this reason, you should not use an `NSBitmapImageRep` object if you
>   want to manipulate image data. To work with data that is not
>   premultiplied, use the Core Graphics framework instead. (Specifically,
>   create images using the `CGImageCreate` function and `kCGImageAlphaLast`
>   parameter.) Alternatively, include the
>   `NSAlphaNonpremultipliedBitmapFormat` flag when creating the bitmap.
>
> > **Note**
> >
> > Use the `bitmapFormat` parameter to the
> >     `initWithBitmapDataPlanes:pixelsWide:pixelsHigh:bitsPerSample:samplesPerPixel:hasAlpha:isPlanar:colorSpaceName:bitmapFormat:bytesPerRow:bitsPerPixel:`
> >     method to specify the format for creating a bitmap. When creating or
> >     retrieving a bitmap with other methods, the bitmap format depends on
> >     the original source of the image data. Check the `bitmapFormat` property
> >     before working with image data.

You have used the `-init...` method *without* the `bitmapFormat` parameter. In that case, you need to query the `bitmapFormat` of the resulting object and make sure you build your pixel values to match that format. Note that the format dictates where the alpha appears in the component order, whether the color components are premultiplied by the alpha, and whether the components are floating point or integer.

You can switch to using the `-init...` method that does have the `bitmapFormat` parameter and specify `NSAlphaNonpremultipliedBitmapFormat` mixed in with your choice of other flags (first or last, integer or floating point, endianness). Note, though, that not all possible formats are supported for drawing.

By the way, I strongly recommend reading the sections about `NSImage` and `NSBitmapImageRep` in the [10.6 AppKit release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/AppKit/RN-AppKitOlderNotes/#X10_6Notes). Search for "NSImage, CGImage, and CoreGraphics impedance matching" and start reading there through the section "NSBitmapImageRep: CoreGraphics impedance matching and performance notes", which is most relevant here. That last section, in particular, has important information about working directly with pixels.

Comment: Thank You! 
Documentation is pretty hard for me: english is not my native language, some terms are very new and as a type designer my computer science background is rather weak.

OK. Funny things happened. When I added <bitmapFormat: NSAlphaFirstBitmapFormat> compiler said — ”Use of unresolved identifier 'NSAlphaFirstBitmapFormat'". I changed it for 0. Compiler said in  <bitmapDataPlanes: nil,> — "'NSBitmapImageRep' is not convertible to 'NSBitmapImageRep'". Really funny. Pretty hard.

Comment: Maybe you can show me right path — I try to build picture in „old way”, pixel by pixel. Each pixel has to be rendered by algorithm which I want to write and check its sense. Experiment, idea, craziness. On top of this I plan to use drawing methods as beziers and rectangles for UX. Later. But now i have to find HOW in most effective way set one pixel in View.

Comment: OK almost works. With added <bitmapFormat: NSBitmapFormat.NSAlphaNonpremultipliedBitmapFormat> color is OK, but alpha makes image darker, not transparent.

Comment: How are you viewing your image? If you are drawing it on a dark background then decreasing the alpha would make it darker.

Comment: I expect this. But unfortunately background is white: 
NSColor.whiteColor().set()
        NSRectFill(dirtyRect)

Comment: rep.drawInRect(bounds) calls rep.draw(). draw uses the NSCompositeCopy composite operation. Transparent (alpha) regions appear black.

Comment: What to do to avoid this effect?

Comment: Use `drawInRect(_:fromRect:operation:fraction:respectFlipped:hints:)` with `.CompositeSourceOver` as the compositing operation.